# I want to thread data read from realm in iOS

Tags: ios, realm

Reading data from ios to realm and using threads at the same time
But "Realm accessed from incorrect thread." An error occurs
Is there a problem with your code?

```
let realm = try! Realm()
        let readData = realm.objects(DataRealm.self)
        for i in 0...readData.count-1 {

            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                self.parsing()
            }
        }
```

Comment: To avoid Realm threading errors, try converting your realm models to your own custom models and pass those around!

Comment: @Rikh That's generally not a solution with Realm as you loose the live updating features of the Realm objects and lists when those objects are cast to your own. Additionally, Realm objects are lazily loaded so you can work with a thousands of objects and only take up a tiny fraction of memory. When converted those objects take up actual memory can can often overwhelm the device.

Comment: Ahhh thanks for that @Jay! I never knew about the auto updates part in realm! Hopefully OP ignores my comment!

Comment: The code in your question works but why are you calling self.parsing within a DispatchQueue inside a tight loop when you're not actually doing anything with the realm objects that were loaded. e.g. That code doesn't do anything. Also, you will probably want a `autoreleasepool` but that's a different topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Realm objects across threads. That's why you get this error.
But you can use references which you can pass across them. 
I am not sure how to apply it to your code since there is no part where you use the individual objects from *readData*. But what you are searching for might be something like this:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let readData = realm.objects(DataRealm.self)
for data in readData {
    let readDataRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: data)
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        self.parsing(readDataReference: readDataRef)
    }
}
```

In your *parsing()* method you would need to get the object from the reference then:

```
let data = realm.resolve(readDataReference)
```

Comment: Actually, as of 5.0 *Realm Frozen Objects... can be read from any thread*.

Comment: Good point, but since there is an exception happening there still seems to be a threading issue

Comment: No disagreement here. Read my comment to the question though.